# Зачем нужно ключевое слово override

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть 2 класса. `Class2` содержит публичный виртуальный метод:

```
    public virtual void fun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
```

`Class1` наследуется от `Class2` и переписывает `fun`

```
class Class1 : Class2
{
    public override void fun()
    {
        base.fun();
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }  
}
```

Если создать объект `Class1` и вызвать `fun`

```
Class1 cl = new Class1();
cl.fun();
```

на консоль будет выведено 1 и 2. Однако если удалить `override` и оставить :

```
class Class1 : Class2
{
    public   void fun()
    {
        base.fun();
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }  
}
```

то на консоль опять же выведет 1 и 2. Вопрос: зачем нужно ключевое слово `override` которое никак не влияет на результат? Понятно, что по идеи мы переписываем виртуальные методы внутри тел методов наследников, но для этого достаточно в базовом классе написать `virtual`, а в наследнике создать одноименный метод и вызвать `base`. Так получается, что слово  `override` не нужно?

Comment: А теперь тот же самый опыт сделай (с override и без), только напиши `Class2 cl = new Class1();`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский разницу вижу. выведет только 1 без `override` но вопрос зачем мне  писать  `Class2 cl = new Class1`  вместо             `Class1 cl = new Class1` ?

Comment: @Сергей, потому что вы должны программировать на уровне интерфейсов, а не реализаций. Здесь интерфейс - уровень абстракции, а не непосредственно `interface` из `C#`

Comment: @Сергей на самом деле ответ кроется  в самом первом комментарии......Причем полиморфизм - это не значит возможность банально переопределить метод родителя с другой логикой.. это нечто бОльшее...... почитайте текст по первой ссылке +  Самый частый пример с фигурами https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ключевое слово `override` нужно не компилятору (он-то прекрасно может увидеть, что метод базового класса виртуальный), а нам с вами, чтобы предотвратить ошибки.

Смотрите, пусть у нас была пара из виртуального метода и его переопределения, и мы переименовали виртуальный метод, а переименовать переопределение забыли. Или мы поменяли сигнатуру базового метода, а при смене сигнатуры переопределённого метода допустили ошибку в порядке аргументов. Или просто имплементируем виртуальный метод, но сделали ошибку в сигнатуре.

Если бы ключевое слово `override` не требовалось, компилятор прекрасно проглотил бы этот код: ну базовый метод виртуальный, а новый метод его не переопределяет, а просто определяет параллельный метод. А вот с ключевым словом `override` компилятор может поднять тревогу: `override` не перекрывает никакой метод, это явная ошибка.

Кроме того, ключевое `override` помогает читателю понять, что это метод в цепочке перекрытий базового метода, и он будет вызван полиморфно. Без него пришлось бы лезть во все базовые классы и подглядывать там, нет ли там случайно виртуального метода с точно такой же сигнатурой.

---

Как отмечает @Алексей Шиманский в комментариях, если опустить ключевое слово `override` в вашем примере, то функция `Class1.fun` будут перекрывать по имени, но не виртуально переопределять функцию базового класса `Class2.fun` (и компилятор пожалуется, что вы не указали ключевое слово `new`, которое означает, что вы так делаете сознательно, а не по ошибке). Для вызова по точному типу объекта разницы нет, но разница будет, если вызывать по ссылке на *базовый тип*:

```
Class2 cl = new Class1();
cl.fun();
```

В этом случае `Class2.fun` и `Class1.fun` — несвязанные функции, и несмотря на `virtual` у `Class2.fun`, будет вызвана лишь функция базового класса.

Смысл виртуальных функций в том и состоит, что по ссылке на базовый класс будет вызвана реализация виртуальной функции из производного класса. (Вы можете не знать точный тип объекта во время выполнения.)

Comment: Хорошо сказано, сам раньше не мог понять зачем он нужен, а сейчас понятно

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy: Спасибо! Я начинал с C++, в котором `override` не было, и это было источником ошибок. Так что я прочувствовал необходимость `override` на собственном опыте.

Comment: Мне кажется ТС имеет в виду то, что [я когда-то имел](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36191408#36191408)  ....... [chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36191498_36191498](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36191498#36191498)   ............. [chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36191824_36191824](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36191824#36191824) :-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Ага, спасибо! Дополнил ответ.

Comment: При этом студия будет просить явно подтвердить что мы имеем ввиду - `new` или `override`. Про `new` тоже неплохо бы добавить.

Comment: @Андрей: Угу, добавил, спасибо!