# Поля(функции) унаследенного класса не видны, кроме переопределенного

Tags: c#, .net, наследование, переопределение

Здрасьте. Когда создаю объект унаследенного класса. Например

```
using System;
class A
{
    public virtual void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is virtual function");
    }
    public void func()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("first function");
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public override void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is override function");
    }
    public void func2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("second function");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A obj;
        B obj2 = new B();
        obj = obj2;
        obj.foo();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

и создаю объект класса B и присваиваю это так obj=obj2, то возникает непонятный случай. То есть, так могу обращатся только функциям (полям) класса A, но одно исключение что могу обращатся функцию public override void foo() из класса B. Как это возможно что, obj не видит аргументы класса B, но видит переопределенные методы ?

Comment: это и есть суть перекрытия/переопределения методов. почитайте про ООП еще раз.

Comment: возможный дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699186/223826

Answer (score 0):

Тут проблема, как я понимаю, слабо связана именно с переопределением методов.

Ваша переменная `obj` имеет тип `A`. Даже присвоив ей ссылку на тип объект типа `B` - переменная не поменяет свой тип. Чтобы было чуть понятнее (надеюсь Вы знаете про интерфейсы):

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void foo();
}

class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
}
..............................

IMyInterface v = new MyClass();
v.foo(); //можно
v.bar(); //нельзя
```

Можно сказать, что мы "не знаем" что в `v` хранится ссылка на объект класса `MyClass`, мы только знаем, что этот объект поддерживает интерфейс `IMyInterface`, ведь объект не может быть создан из интерфейса. Но мы можем создать переменную более общего типа, чем реальное значение. Вообще, обычно так и делают, чтобы отвязаться от реализации:

```
void SendData(IData data) {...}
```

Метод получает объект, реализующий `IData`. Нам в контексте метода всё равно какого именно типа будет объект, мы будем работать только с теми свойствами и методами, которые предоставляет интерфейс `IData`

Еще пример:

```
object v = new List<int>();
v.Add(5); // неа
```

Чтобы лучше разобраться, Вам следует почитать про полиморфизм. При первом изучении это может быть сложно. Но нужно брать разные источники, чтобы в итоге все-таки понять, т.к. без этого дальше в ООП Вы не продвинетесь.